# Can I use 4G LTE (Cellular Data) and Airplay using Wifi w/ No Internet connection at the same time?

Tags: iphone, wifi, appletv, airplay, cellular-data

I've looked for an answer to this but still haven't found one that works.

I want to use my iPhone as my primary source of internet. I am currently an ATT Uverse DSL customer, but I want to cut the cord and use our current DSL modem/router, the one and only Motorola NVG510 for it's wireless signal only so that my wife and I can airplay from our phones to our Apple TV.

Is it possible to use our Cell Data to stream a video and then airplay that streaming video to our Apple TV at the same time?

*Using the iPhone as a hotspot is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

See my response to this question on the Apple discussions.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5770041?tstart=0

Basically, use a static configuration for your WiFi Network, but leave the Router IP address blank.  The LTE icon will be displayed, and the mobile network used for all non-local traffic (ie, Internet) but you will still be connected to the WiFi network can can use all local LAN resources.

Edit:  I also notice you said use it as your primary Internet connection.  I originally assumed that you meant *only for the iPhone.*  If so, then my response above should work for you.  If you meant use it as your primary Internet connection for all other devices (laptops, etc) in your home, then of course the only way to do that *IS* to use your iPhone as a hot spot.  That's kind of the definition of a hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix and YouTube is not possible. I have not found this info anywhere but Apple and/or Netflix apparently do not allow AirPlay without Wifi. Using the latest Apple TV A1469 "EMC 2633" you are able to AirPlay without wifi from iOS 7 or later but if you try to "mirror" Netflix or YouTube you will receive error messages and the videos will not play. Hulu works

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible.  We do it in our camper.  Generic router or access point, connect your phone to the wifi signal (sometimes it takes a while because it says no internet, after a bit it asks you if you want to continue without internet, say yes); connect your apple TV to the same access point. On your PHONE, go into Settings - WiFi, and select the network you are connecting to without internet, then select the little 'i' on the right.  Then select "Static". Set IP address to 10.0.1.4 and subnet mask to 255.255.0.0

Leave all other blank.

This will ensure your phone looks to cellular for internet connection, but allows the wifi necessary for AirPlay.  Just make sure you have a fast enough wifi access point/router or you'll have trouble. Also, some apps WANT wifi internet to work right.  But the other poster is correct: Netflix and Youtube (google) bind you with HDMI encruption BULLSH*T.  They are attempting to force you to buy services coming and going.  They don't make it easy!

Answer (score 0):

This does work, im assuming the goal is to get rid of buffering from the typical poor wifi you get at hotels and campgrounds. The problem is the wifi connection to the Apple TV suffers too so the resolution goes way down or you still get some buffering.